# Integrate $\sqrt{4 - x^2}\cdot\operatorname{sgn}(x-1)$

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

I'm trying to learn calculus through self study and I happened upon the following exercise:

$$ \int_{0}^{2} \sqrt{4 - x^2}\cdot\operatorname{sgn}(x-1) \,dx $$

Seeing the sgn I thought: well this is easy and concluded that since $ \int_{0}^{2} \operatorname{sgn}(x-1) \,dx = 0$, the answer should be zero. But of course then I remembered that $ \int  f(x)g(x) \,dx \neq \int f(x) \,dx \int g(x) \,dx$ and got lost.

I know how to solve $ \int_{0}^{2} \sqrt{4 - x^2}dx$, since that geometrically corresponds to a quarter circle of radius $2$ it's just $\pi$, but how do I approach the product of these things?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That integral is equal to$$-\int_0^1\sqrt{4-x^2}\,\mathrm dx+\int_1^2\sqrt{4-x^2}\,\mathrm dx.$$So, all you have to do is to compute those two integrals. In order to do that, it is usful to know that$$\int\sqrt{4-x^2}\,\mathrm dx=\frac12x\sqrt{4-x^2}+2\arcsin\left(\frac{x}{2}\right).$$

Comment: Thanks, I can sort of follow this; $f(x) = sgn(x - 1)$, so if $x \in [0, 1)$, then $-1$ and when $x \in (1, 2]$ it's $1$ and you basically can split the integrand. I tried this for a simpler one: $\int_{0}^{2} 2x sgn(x)$  and this works out, but I fail to articulate or see a more general rule I can distill from this, it feels a bit hacky at the moment.

Comment: You need to figure out when the quantity $sgn(y)$ changes sign. This gives you the point(s) where you need to split the integral.

Comment: Note that$$\operatorname{sgn}(x-1)=\begin{cases}-1&\text{ if }x<1\\1&\text{ if }x\geqslant1\end{cases}$$and that therefore$$\operatorname{sgn}(x-1)\sqrt{4-x^2}=\begin{cases}-\sqrt{4-x^2}&\text{ if }x<1\\\sqrt{4-x^2}&\text{ if }x\geqslant1.\end{cases}$$

Comment: Got it, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To expand on @José Carlos Santos' answer, you can compute $\int \sqrt{4-x^2}\; dx$ by trigonometric substitution: let $x=2\sin(t)$ with $-\frac{\pi}{2}\le t\le \frac{\pi}{2}$ . Then $\sqrt{4-x^2}=2\cos(t)$ and $dx=2\cos(t)\; dt$ so

$$\int \sqrt{4-x^2}\; dx = \int 4\cos^2(t)\; dt = 2 \int 1+\cos(2t)\; dt 
= 
2\left(t + \frac{\sin(2t)}{2} \right)+ C$$

Substituting back, we get

$$\int \sqrt{4-x^2}\; dx = 2 \arcsin\left(\frac x 2\right) + \frac{x\sqrt{4-x^2}}{2} + C$$

Therefore,

$$\int_{0}^{2} \sqrt{4 - x^2}\cdot\operatorname{sgn}(x-1) \,dx
=
-\int_0^1\sqrt{4-x^2}\,\mathrm dx+\int_1^2\sqrt{4-x^2}\,\mathrm dx
=
-\left(2\arcsin(1/2)+\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}
\right) 
+
\left(2\arcsin(1)-2\arcsin(1/2)-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}
\right)
=\frac{\pi}{3}-\sqrt{3}$$